# Please could someone clarify and explain what is meant by an ideal, and the generators of an ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I'm starting my undergrad degree in a month and wanted to get familiar with some of the content beforehand. I've been covering Serge Lang's **'Undergraduate Algebra'** over the past two weeks and I've come to the part where he discusses **ideals and generators**. I understand that an ideal is a subset of the integers that has three key properties. However, I'm struggling to understand what exactly he means by the generators of an ideal. Furthermore, he outlines a theorem that states:

Let m1, m2 be positive integers. Let d be a positive generator
for the ideal generated by m1,m2. Then d is the greatest common
divisor of m1 and m2.

How can d be a generator when m1 and m2 already generated the ideal?

Bearing in mind that this is in **chapter 1.3** and he hasn't discussed groups or rings yet, please could someone cast some light on this as I'm pretty confused.

Thanks

Comment: As you have noted, an ideal might have multiple sets of generators.  For instance the ideal of Even numbers is generated by $2$, but also by $\{4,6\}$ or by $\{14,-32\}$  *Principal* ideals can be generated by single elements but there are examples of ideals which are not principal (not in the ring of integers, but in other sorts of rings).

Comment: Thank you, that cleared it up.

Comment: I think , taken with the comment by user @lulu , this [[ https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2007/05/13/generators-of-ideals/ ]] covers the Post.

Answer (score 1):

I think light has already been shed but I will show why the ideal generated by two integers $n,m$ is the ideal generated by their gcd.

Let $d=\gcd(n,m)$ this means by definition: $d|n,d|m$ and for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $k|m,k|n$ we have $k|d$.

Clearly, $(n,m)\subset (d)$ as $d$ divides both $n$ and $m$. By the euclidean algorithm there are $r,s\in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $d=rn+sm$, so $(d)\subset (n,m)$.